# how to implement php in html file

Tags: php, html

so I'm basically brand new to web based stuff. My university has given me a cPanel hosted server. I need to implement some basic php functions for my main web page.

This is what my cpanel looks like if it helps:

[image]

So in my index.html file I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Current Date/Time</title>
</head>

<body>
<h3>
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date("l");
echo "Hello World!";
?>
</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

But none of the php echo stuff is displaying. I'm not sure if my server actually knows what to do with an html file with php in it.

My instructors have told me: the php file needs to be deployed to public_html folder using the file manager in CPanel.

But i'm not really sure what needs to go into the .php file and how to get my .html file to utilize it.

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I'd first get a static html file working (without any PHP).  So you know what folder it belongs in.  Then add your PHP (which looks fine).  But outside of that, it's kind of hard to help you.

Comment: your file extension should be .php not .html

Comment: index.php not ndex.html

Comment: HTML file is only html, but PHP work for both php and html, so rename this file as .php extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file's extension needs to be changed from *.html to *.php or the PHP won't execute, it'll just be treated like raw HTML.

Here's a quick very basic step-by-step of what's happening:

1. The client requests index.php
2. Your web server recognizes the *.php extension and tells PHP to interpret it
3. PHP parses the text looking for PHP code, and evaluates that code, then replaces the PHP code with the output of that PHP code (if any)

   For example:

   ```
   $strVar = 'world';
   echo '<span class="contentText">hello ' . $strVar . '</span><br />';
   ```

   is replaced with that code's output:

   ```
   <span class="contentText">hello world</span><br />
   ```
4. The resulting HTML is then returned to the client as content to be rendered by the client's web browser
5. The client's web browser parses the HTML and renders a web page

Answer (score 3):

Your file name needs to be .php. If the web server is set up with PHP (which I'm going to assume it is) then it will handle the php file fine.

Rename the index.html for now and by default the index.php will be the first page to load.

Answer (score 2):

The file you are using is index.html. This means that it can only display static text and that's the reason why your PHP code is not working.

All you have to do is change the extension from .html to .php then your PHP code should work.

Although I would suggest you Google a few Intro. to HTML and PHP tutorials to get you going on the basics