# Run PHP into *.html extension (mime type)

Tags: php, html

I have xampp and I have a project that extensions are 
*. html and php code have my localhost php does not interpret the code and displays it as php, but I want to run as php code ex:
index.html

```
 <?php
      $seccion='inicio';
      require_once("idiomas.html");
      require_once("configurador.html");
      require_once("header_scripts_css.html");
    ?>

    <body class="clearfix">
      <header id="header">
        <?php require_once("header.html"); ?>
      </header>
      <?php require_once("slider.html"); ?>
      <div id="centro">
        <?php require_once("central.html");?>
      </div>
      <?php require_once("footer.html"); ?>
```

Comment: You can't run PHP in a .html file.

Comment: @TomKriek Yes you can. PHP will process any file you ask it to if you look in the right place.

Comment: @TomKriek: You can if you tell the server to process `.html` files via PHP.

Comment: why don't you just change the file extensions to *.php ?

Comment: @Tim Cooper tried this but not working in htaccess think it has to do with httpd.conf and mime.types files

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951890/how-to-implement-php-in-html-file?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532843/how-to-parse-php-syntax-in-a-html-file-on-server?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-to-html-files

Answer (score 4):

you can add

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`

into your `.htaccess` file or you can modify apache mod-php5 setting

Comment: If adding to htaccess the op needs to ensure he has his allowoverride set appropriately. It may best for security just to change it in httpd.conf or apache2.conf depending on your distro.

Comment: don't work variables reads as html code includes etc. ..

Comment: You will still need to include the proper php tags, and after changing your configuration make sure you restart your apache.

Comment: yes my apache has restarted

Comment: I use this method to configure .ptr extensions with my domain, and it works perfectly. Please post more of your apache configuration and maybe we can help you.

Comment: couldn't agree more Justin E. It is better to add into the FilesMatch block in the config

Comment: It is a clean install of xampp, the latest version

Comment: This: AddType application/x-httpd-php .html works, but you need the PHP tags in your html file <?php echo "<html>your html content</html>"; ?>

Comment: that is uploaded to a domain, it works fine as you can see does not give any error variables, but in my localhost does not load, and all the php code in html code shown http://1080lol.com/newPanorama/index.php (index.php is a php but, all files include has html extension

Comment: Please post your xampp configuration file. Use pastebin. Maybe then you can actually get somewhere.

Comment: Did you allow override ?